# How can I create a custom attribute/property on a model?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, mvc

In my custom component, I'm currently stuck with Joomla's way of handling model custom properties. Let's say I have a model `Property`. To know if this `Property` is sold, I have to run a query on multiple columns. There's date_sold, but there's also buyer. Both fields have to be checked before being able to say that the Property is sold.

In my view, I can do `if ($property->date_sold ... && $property->buyer ...)`, but is there a way to say `if ($property->is_sold)`?

I tried in my `view.html.php`:

```
$this->is_sold = 0;
if (!is_null($this->property->buyer) && $this->property->date_sold) {
    $this->is_sold = 1;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Strangely, var_dump is outputting null, but print_r is outputting 1.

The only way I've found to do this is in the template (`default.php`). What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you're describing. You may want to check for "I've been staring at this too long" errors... eg: if you're using `$this->is_sold` in your view.html.php are you using `$property->is_sold` in your tpl file? Because you should be using `$this->is_sold`.

Comment: That if clause is handling your date_sold as a boolean. I am assuming you are using a datetime or unix timestamp in your database. Revise your if to handle the clause appropriately and see what happens. Also make sure your buyer field in the database is nullable, or if it is just a null string. Try if != null instead of !is_null.

Answer (score 1):

#### Table

You can modify a Table object (usualy in `/administrator/com_yourcomponent/tables/property.php`) of this Property to set the `is_sold` property in `load` method right after `parent::load()`.

#### Model

Other way is to modify the model (`/components/com_yourcomponent/models/property.php`). You modify method `getItem()` by adding a proper checking code after `parent::getItem()`.

#### View

You can also do it in your `view.html.php` but without a full code its hard to give you a straight answer why what you wrote doesn't work. One tip, if you want to check if item was sold its better to check if date was set like this `!empty($this->property->date_sold)` or by checking if this is not a zero date.